# Byte enum comparison in C#

Tags: c#, enums

Given this enum

```
public enum UserStatus : byte
{
    Approved = 1,
    Locked = 2,
    Expire = 3
}
```

why does this check always return false when `usr.Status = 1`

```
if(usr.Status.Equals(UserStatus.Approved))
    return true;
return false;
```

The comparison seems to work - there is no compile time error or runtime exception. Please note I am not the author of this piece of code and would like to find out why the author chose enum of type `byte` and why this doesn't work as it should.

Comment: Re "no error"; since you are using the boxed version, almost anything is legal. If, however, you use the more-appropriate `==`, it will tell you: `Error [number] Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'byte' and 'UserStatus'`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you will have to cast.

The equals method will check if `UserStatus` is an `int` (depending on the type you have defined at the property `usr.Status`). It will then return that is not (it is of type `UserStatus`) thus return `false`

Better code would be:

```
return usr.Status == (int)UserStatus.Approved;
```

Comment: Even better would be to declare your `Status` as `UserStatus` and not just `int`. After all, it represents a `UserStatus`, isn't it?

Comment: Also, if you used `usr.Status == UserStatus.Approved` then the compiler would warn you about these sorts of things.

Comment: @Vlad that is true. The reason I wrote it that way was because he didn't post the code. It also could be a generated class, from linq for example, where you cannot set the type to `UserStatus`

Comment: Re better code... as per my comment on the question, I would advise `==` here, since the compiler will report errors on `==`, but not on `Equals`

Answer (score 8):

The first thing any Equals implementation usually checks is: "is this the right type". And `UserStatus` is ***not*** the same as `byte`.

(actually, this only happens because you have *boxed* the items via your incompatible use of `Equals`; at the IL level they are indistinguishable until boxed)

You must compare them as items *of the same type*. To borrow some code from `byte`:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return ((obj is byte) && (this == ((byte) obj)));
}
```

Comment: So basically casting the enum to byte before the comparison? Internal value will not change given that it will still be a byte right?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou from `object` to an `enum` or to `byte` is an *unboxing* operation - it will *extract* the internal value (from the box) *as* the `enum`-type or `byte`. That doesn't change the value *in the box* in any way - it is untouched. The *extracted* value is just a raw primitive value (in this case, on the stack). It will have the same underlying value as it had before. If that isn't what you were asking, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `Usr.Status` contains an Integer and the `UserStatus.Approved` returns an String i.e., `Approved`. So, an integer of value `1` can not be equal to the String `Approved`. So, you must convert the Enum status also to an integer by the following code

```
if (usr.Status == (int)(UserStatus.Approved))
                return true;
       return false;
```

Comment: Enum values are never strings, you chose the storage type in the declaration. Even if they were, you can't cast a string to an integer, so your solution would not work ;-)

Comment: Here the Casting is done not to the String but to the Status of the "Approved" in UserStatus Enum, so it will return 1.

Comment: Yes, and you just said above UserStatus.Approved always returns a string, which would not be castable. Mind you, your solution works, but your explanation is just plain wrong.